# link python version with ipython

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have two versions of python, namely 2.7 and 3.3. Each time I launch ipython it tells me

```
Python 3.3.4 (default, Feb 11 2014, 15:56:08)
```

How do I do to launch ipython with the python 2.7? I always use the ipython notebook, do I need also to change something in it?

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: Linux brother-eye 3.12.9-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jan 31 10:22:54 CET 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have only installed IPython for Python 3 on your system. Arch uses Py3 by default, I believe, so when you installed the [`ipython`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/ipython/) package and its dependencies it was actually `ipython3`. Try installing the [`ipython2`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/ipython2/) package, along with its dependencies. Once completed, you will have a `/usr/bin/ipython2` command for running IPython using Python 2.7.

However, before installing, double-check to see if `/usr/bin/ipython2` exists. If it does, you're all set, and shouldn't need to install anything else.